# referential location with android (non gps, non cell tower , non wifi)

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-wifi, android-sensors

My intention is to track a mobile device with respect to another mobile device or wifi.
i am looking for some pointers to proceed on building a location tracking system something that does not depend in gps for location tracking instead.

A possible set of approaches might be.

1. user can click on "start" button on mobile which will be the origin and then start tracking the position w.r.t that origin tracking the direction changes.
2. A tracking system that depends on Wifi or another mobile device to locate itself
3. Is it possible for android device to know distance between them , if yes is it possible to know the direction as well?

I would like to get this done on android device , is this possible?  i have given lot of search before posting this, so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi localisation is possible with sensor fusion (still in research for better accuracy).

There are many papers available on this topic in net

http://www.cs.stanford.edu/people/dstavens/icra11/huang_etal_icra11.pdf

http://personal.stevens.edu/~ychen6/mobi248_liu.pdf

http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/2011/8/RobustIndoorLocalizationTech2011.pdf